# asp.Net MVC web application to be deployed on SharePoint

Tags: development, web-part, sharepoint-addin, asp.net

We have a new project that at some point has to be deployed in sharepoint environment. We were thinking of building that as a regular .net application and later deploy it to sharepoint.

Here are some of the questions:

1) can we deploy an asp.net MVC web application having its data source on SQL azure directly to sharepoint?

2) Any special design considerations  from design and deployment perspective keeping in mind that it has to be deployed on sharepoint?

3) Application database will be on SQL azure instead of sharepoint lists. Will that be ok?

4) We may have to make use of workflows. Will it create a problem if we don't use sharepoint lists as a data source?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean that asp.net web application will be deployed to SharePoint ? do you mean a server where SharePoint is installed ? What would be your approach to deploy asp.net application on SharePoint ?

Comment: I mean that the priority is to build an asp.net web application and later it is envisioned to be part of other intranet applications on sharepoint. One way is to build a sharepoint web app using lists as its data source and Front-end (GUI) can be done using info path whereas the other way I see is to build an ASP.net MVC application and then deploy it in sharepoint. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some valuable info I found on the following [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sanjaynarang/2009/06/19/should-i-build-my-application-in-sharepoint-vs-asp-net/)

However, I still feel that I need a little more research and concrete answers to my asked and unasked questions. Some of the unasked queries may be more implicit.

Adding more content from the original blog.

Many times, I get question from my customers if they should build a new application in SharePoint or ASP.net. For certain kind of applications such as Collaboration or KM Portal, Internet facing web site, intranet social networking site, applications requiring browser enabled forms or Enterprise Search, SharePoint is THE option to go for.

However, it’s not a straight forward answer for all types of applications. You need to look at different aspects before deciding. I’ve put a high level list of questions that I use to make such decisions. Hopefully, the questions should help you also.

What are the features that you are going to use out-of-the-box (OOB) from SharePoint (site provisioning, search, version control, roles/groups, easy forms (list edit, new, view pages), collaboration, workflows, content deployment, alerts ) )
The list of feature is huge, have a look at evaluation guides for complete list: WSS, SharePoint and Search
If you are not using any of these features what’s it that you’d gain from SharePoint?
If you need these features, why are you thinking of not going with SharePoint? What’s the effort if you custom build those features?
What are the features that I’m going to build custom (for example, reports for some applications would be custom and need relational tables with transactional support)
How much effort is required for custom development in ASP.net vs. in SharePoint? Is the difference huge?
What kind of application it is? Is it one off application, or this is going to replicated across many teams. SharePoint is an excellent platform where you need to replicate one type of site to many teams.
What are the required Scale and Performance objectives of your application
SharePoint has some boundaries, most of these can be avoided with adjusted design or workaround. Would the adjusted design or workaround be acceptable to your users? Examples:
2000 list items at a single level – a well know limitation
2000 security principles for a securable object – a lesser known limitation, but this can create problems when users in a site collection grows more than 2000 – there are workarounds for this (such as using AD security groups) – are those acceptable?
SharePoint may not be able to match the performance of a plain ASP.net application as it does a lot more work (security trimming, getting files from database etc.) Can your performance targets be met using SharePoint?
You can check benchmarks published by Microsoft or other vendors (such as HP, Intel) to see if SharePoint can meet your requirements. Links to most of the benchmarks are available in this blog post: SharePoint (Performance, Stress ) Load Testing 
How many employees would be using these application? How many requests you can expect for customization from different teams. Remember, SharePoint provides a pretty good platform for customization and personalization.
How much time do you have to build such apps? Can you use some off-the-shelf solutions? For examples, there are many custom applications which be deployed in no time by using WSS Application Templates (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb407286.aspx)
What’s the cost you can afford. Remember, you need not buy any separate license, if you are only using Windows SharePoint Services. Have a look at difference of features between WSS and MOSS in the comparison Excel spreadsheet.
What skills your developers have? Though SharePoint is based on ASP.net, but you need have additional knowledge to develop SharePoint applications. Also, development is SharePoint is not like normal .NET development (for example, you don’t get WYSWYG designer to develop web parts for SharePoint). You also need to take extra care to follow same build and source control process that you do for .Net code. Have a look at Application Lifecycle Management Resource Center for SharePoint Server for more details.

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Made the required changes and added content from the original blog post.

Answer (score 0):

yes it makes sense, but when you create a asp.net web application it would be deployed in IIS and this IIS can be any server(SharePoint or non-SharePoint server). in ideal case why would someone deploy asp.net application on SharePoint Farm ? you can use different application server and deploy your asp.net application there. Now coming to you envisioned asp.net be part of other intranet application on SharePoint, please note this would be just a link out from your SharePoint application and if you want you can configure single sign on so that both SharePoint intranet application and your asp.net application works with same user tokens....

please mark it as answer if this makes sense...

Comment: I have multiple questions. Your comments does provide me some information, however, I need more relevant information for my questions. We may also want to utilize sharepoint 's workflow capability. And I do not want just a link of my application in the sharepoint portal. It is not only single sign-on but also workflow capability. But thanks for your response; appreciate your inputs.

Comment: you can always use our SharePoint application for workflow capabilities, but as far as my knowledge goes, you cannot deploy a asp.net application on SharePoint... the terminology itself does not make sense... yes one thing you can do it you can build your asp.net application and show it in your SharePoint page using pageviewwebpart or iframe....